# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i'm new in JavaScript

Code :-

```
strPreEvo = '<span class="'(item.previous_evolution_updown == "up") ? 'increase-text' : (item.previous_evolution_updown == "down") ? 'decrease-text''">';
```

problem :- **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'` **

Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you want?

Comment: When i return strPreEvo Than getting this error @HoldOffHunger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement needs a string operation after `'<span class="'`, probably a `+`.  Then that last conditional needs a `:` to delimit `'decrease-text'`and `'">'`

```
let strPreEvo = '<span class="' +  // <-- note the operation

(item.previous_evolution_updown == "up") ? 'increase-text' :  // fine for this part of the condition

(item.previous_evolution_updown == "down") ? 'decrease-text' : '">';  // <--- note the colon
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra "'" quotation mark at the end. The correct code would be

```js
strPreEvo = '<span class="'(item.previous_evolution_updown == "up") ? 'increase-text' : (item.previous_evolution_updown == "down") ? 'decrease-text'">';
```